# Swift keep reference to old array

Tags: arrays, swift

Please consider following code:

```
func arrayEcludingDivingByP (p: Int, arrToCheck : [Int]) -> Array<Int>{

    var  tmp : [Int] = []

    for (ob, index) in arrToCheck.enumerated() {

        var isDividible : Bool = ob % p == 0 ? true : false

        if (!isDividible){
            tmp.append(ob)
        }
    }

    return tmp
}

var p : Int = 2

func getSimpleNumbersArrayFromArray (p : Int, arrPassed : [Int]) -> Array <Int>{

    var tmp : [Int] = []
    tmp = arrPassed

    for i in 0...5 {
        tmp = arrayEcludingDivingByP(p: p+i, arrToCheck: tmp)
        print("tmp array? \(tmp)")

    }
    return tmp


}
```

`arrayEcludingDivingByP` function simply return new array without items that multiplied for specific multiplier (p) without division.

```
getSimpleNumbersArrayFromArray contain loop for 6 iterates, that should output array, which Int objects are not dividible by 0...5 accordingly.
```

But somehow it always keep referrence to old array, which is array of numbers from 1 to 100. In console it output following:

```
tmp array? [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97]
tmp array? [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Why it happen? It should not contain even numbers in second iteration but it does.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: As I understand you created some kind of Filter? When your Array 0 - 100 comes you try to divide by `p` every Value which is not dividable should be removed for the next run right? If I am right, his problem is, that in the next turn it seems, that it starts again with the array from the beginning. e.g. the first array does not have a 2 the next one has it and so on with other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your enumeration wrong. First element is the index, second element is the actual item (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)):

```
for (index, ob) in arrToCheck.enumerated() {
...
```

That should solve your issue.